# Chrome 92 rendering CSS a bit differently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I have this piece of code which until last week when I was using Chrome 86.x was working fine but now after having updated Chrome, the CSS is a bit off. Currently I'm on `Version 92.0.4515.131` of Chrome

On Chrome 86.x and FireFox 90.0.2, there was no gap between the `Some Text` and `Search` input. But now on Chrome 92.x there seems to be this space between those two elements.

After inspecting, if I remove the flex-basis of `100%` it works and it looks fine on both Chrome 86 and 92. There are several areas of my code, where I seem to be facing this issue and removing the flex-basis everywhere does not seem to be a solution.

Is this a bug on Chrome where it is misinterpreting the flex-basis?

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <style type="text/css">
         .Wrapper--3Ct6E > div {
         height: 100%; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; place-content: stretch space-between; align-items: stretch;">
         <div class="Wrapper--3Ct6E">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; place-content: stretch flex-start; align-items: stretch;">
               <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; place-content: stretch flex-start; align-items: stretch;">
                  <div style="max-width: 100%; flex: 1 0 100%;">
                     <div>
                        <span>Some Text </span> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input placeholder="Search" type="text" disabled="" value=""> 
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```